# What would be a good Selection function in a genetic algorithm to find a target number?

Tags: python, algorithm, artificial-intelligence, genetic-algorithm

I'm writing a genetic algorithm to find an expression that expresses a target number, i.e. if the target number is `10` a solution could be `2*5`. I'm running into scenarios where my whole population becomes one identical chromosome and I think that the fitness function is in charge for this.

The following are possible chromosomes, obeying the rules that numbers and operators appears in the string alternately, in a way that no two digits or two operators are adjacent. A legal string would start with a digit or `+/-` operators. The expression would be calculated from left to right as-is (ignoring the order of arithmetic operations):

- `1/2+3+5`
- `-2+4+1+8`
- `-7+6*2+8`
- `+2/5-1+8 2+1*2-2`
- `+2*7*7+3`
- `+1/2/2/6 5/5*9*1`
- `+3-1+1*8 3-8+7*1`

Selection():

```
    def selection(population):
        total_finesses = Decimal(0.0)

        # Roulette selection:
        for chromosome in population:
            total_finesses += chromosome .fitness
        # Generate random number (spin the roulette).
        pick = Decimal(random.uniform(0, float(total_finesses)))
        current = Decimal(0.0)

        for i, chrom in enumerate(population):
            current += chrom.fitness
            if current > pick:
                return population[i]
```

Fitness():

```
    def fitness_calculator(chromosome):
        current_value = get_value(chromosome) # Returns the decimal value of the chromosome.

        return Decimal(-1 * (abs(target - current_value), 5))
```

As you can see, the fitness is considered better as it gets closer to 0, since I'm looking for the expression that expresses the number with the lowest delta between itself and the target number.

I think I have a problem with the Selection algorithm, to choose the *lowest* fitted chromosomes in a roulette approach.

Comment: The question you are asking is too broad; picking an appropriate fitness function is entirely down to the precise question you're trying to ask, and has little utility for future users. Also, your implementation of GAs seems a bit odd, I would expect to see: 1. function for randomly generating initial population; 2. function for evaluating fitness of a member of the population; 3. function for *combining* members of the population to create the next generation; and 4. function for controlling which members should be combined.

Comment: @jonrsharpe How exactly is it odd? What makes you think the functions you mentioned aren't implemented? How can a GA be a GA without the mentioned functions? I just though that they're irrelevant to the question, thus I didn't paste them as well.

Comment: *"How can a GA be a GA without the mentioned functions?"* - my point exactly! If you're only asking about the fitness function in isolation, be clearer about the issue with it. If you have a problem with the overall GA, please give a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Again, though, *"what would be a good selection function"* is **not** an on-topic question.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Maybe I wasn't clear enough. I think that my selection algorithm is faulty. Since the selection algorithm is based on the fitness levels I've also shared the fitness calculator. If this is too broad or an off-topic, well, I'll bite my lips and have the question closed...

Comment: Then could you be clearer about what you mean by *"faulty"*? Inputs and expected and actual outputs (use `random.seed` to remove the effects of randomness for testing) would be helpful - what are the failing cases? Have you tested the fitness function in isolation; does it give correct results for given members of the population?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I will be using a static seed to remove randomness effects and have more information soon, that's a great tip!

Comment: "I'm running into scenarios where my whole population becomes one identical chromosome and I think that the fitness function is in charge for this." If the fitness function thinks that that particular chromosome/solution is the best, then is it surprising that it pervades the population? Do you have anything in place to ensure that all members of the population are unique? Should you?

Comment: @TomDalton It's the best out of the given population, but not the optimal. I do have a function to test if a given chromosome contains the optimal solution to the problem.

Comment: It looks like your selection algorithm randomly chooses the next generation, rather than choosing the best X. So I would expect it to pick the best one several times if the best one is [significantly] better than the rest. So it would be expected that the population would converge on many copies of the best, and then you're relying on mutation alone to make improvements. For a GA to work, you need to make sure that the crossover and mutation are both effective, but your selection function works against that. You might have more luck if you just select the X fittest individuals each round.

Comment: @TomDalton I'm also applying Elitism to preserve the 10% best individuals of each generation, but I'm now writing the ineffective selection from scratch with the help on NumPy

Comment: What's the purpose of taking the best 10% and then a semi-random-but-weighted-towards-the-best selection of the rest? E.g. Why not just take the top 50%? It sounds like the issue isn't the selection per-se but the fact you allow multiple identical individuals in the pool.

Comment: @TomDalton Is it not allowed in a GA to have multiple identical individuals?

Comment: "I'm running into scenarios where my whole population becomes one identical chromosome". Isn't that the problem you are trying to solve? Also, it's not a question of allowed or not, it's a question of does it make sense. Since it makes a crossover operation meaningless, it ultimately harms the operation of the GA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I answered my a similar question on the computer science stackexchange [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/37295/25708) which explains in the best way possible how to find out which is a good selection method for your problem.

However it doesn't look as thought you have implemented mutation which is responsible for maintaining diversity in the population; so you might consider implementing that in some way. Several methods can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutation_%28genetic_algorithm%29).

@TomDalton also makes some fair points in the comments to your question. If having several identical solutions in your pool is causing a problem, don't allow it. Also, randomised selection is rarely a good idea and can often render the evaluation function useless. Your evaluation function ranks the solutions in the pool. Use it! Some methods say take the best solutions and mate them to make the best better; and others says take worst solutions to keep all solutions pretty decent. On top of that there are a ton of other possible selection methods you can choose from.

My final point is this (though it may not apply to your directly it might help people who end up in this thread) a fine tuned initial population size is often underestimated when looking at GAs. Make sure you try a few variations of that too.

Reading material:

Miller, B. L., & Goldberg, D. E. (1995). Genetic algorithms, tournament selection, and the effects of noise. Complex Systems, 9(3), 193-212.

Goldberg, D. E., & Deb, K. (1991). A comparative analysis of selection schemes used in genetic algorithms. Urbana, 51, 61801-2996.

Poon, P. W., & Carter, J. N. (1995). Genetic algorithm crossover operators for ordering applications. Computers & Operations Research, 22(1), 135-147.

Comment: How can I control the initial population other than the length of the chromosomes? Everything else is randomized.

Comment: Plus, why would I want to encode the mathematical expression into binary code? I've seen lots of solutions online that do so. Are they doing it in-order to apply the genetic operations easily?

Comment: You don't change the length of chromosomes, you change how many chromosomes are in the initial pool.

Comment: Binary makes crossover and mutation much easier for the algorithm to calculate. It a large part of the reason of why GAs are so fast.